# Xpages Extension lib installation

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

After installing the extenstion lib latest version for 8.5.3 Notes Designer, I see only the tags I do not see the pictoreal representation of the tags.. any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

Check Database properties so the extension library is checked there. [How to enable Ext Lib](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Extension_Library_enablement_ddxl853)

And also chech the top of the xpage there should be 2 name spaces defined there.[Ext Lib Name Space](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Extension_Library_namespace_ddxl853)

Comment: +1 for mentioning namespace. It happens when I copy just part of the source - namespace is added by designer only on first drag&drop of ExtLib component from palette.

Answer (score 1):

Check which update site of the Extension Library you installed. There is a specific update site that includes Domino Designer tooling called updateSiteOpenNTF-designer.zip. It sounds like you may have just installed the updateSiteOpenNTF.zip update site.

I've not tried, but installing from the -designer update site may install just the additional plugins required. This will avoid you needing to uninstall the Extension Library.