# POI 4 XPages installation (site.xml)

Tags: xml, apache-poi, xpages, lotus-domino

I find this website (http://poi4xpages.openntf.org/) for install POI 4 in domino designer.

I download the zip file and follow the installation guide from https://my.webgate.biz/poi/documentation.nsf/viewdoc.xsp?docid=installguide

In step 2: Import the update site from the ZIP file into the eclipse update site. I try to import the site.xml file but I get an error.

The error is like this:

Object variable not set(#91) 
dlgimportsite: click (line 9)

I open site.xml and check line 9, the code is like this

```
<category-def name="Apache POI Integration" label="Apache POI Integration"/>
```

I don't know why I get the error because I download the file and extract it. In that progress, I did not edit any anything.

I search on the internet and tried the solution from this link and still get the error.
http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Plugins%20Deployment%20for%20Domino/defects/2FEA2A74F1C2751686257863004F6CC6

I read this post [Xpages Extension lib installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679742/xpages-extension-lib-installation) but I cannot get the idea.

What is the problem in site.xml? What should I do with it?

Grateful if someone can advice on this issue.

Thank you very much.

Best Regards,

beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this is the answer http://www.intec.co.uk/using-the-update-site-object-variable-note-set/

If you install into Designer first, you need to shut down and restart Notes

Comment: Dear @Paul Stephen Withers, thank you for your answer. May I ask one question? I closed the Designer and Notes, then restart them and follow the installation guide, I still get the same error. So do I need to restart the server?

Comment: Dear @Paul Stephen Withers and all, I would like to refer to my previous comment, I ask the Domino-Administrator to restart the Domino Server. After that, I shut down and restart the Domino Designer and Notes. I redo the installation but the error still appears when I import the site.xml file (I don't know why it happens again). Grateful for your advice. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you very much.

Comment: The server isn't involved here, if it's not installing the site.xml and plugins and features. That's just Notes client code, importing jar files as attachments to Notes documents. Similarly, if a user had a problem adding attachments to a Notes document in the client, restarting the client wouldn't have any effect. The error, same as any other LotusScript code, it's an error on line 9 of the code on the button click, not anything to do with the site.xml. Can you import any other plugin, e.g. ExtLib? Also, Notes client version may be relevant.

Comment: The article Paul pointed to has the solution (worked for me): close the Notes client and Designer, next only start the Notes client, open the update site database and do the import. Do this all the time (using a 9.0.1 client).

Comment: Dear @Paul Stephen Withers, thank you for your comment. The Domino-Administrator told me Notes client and the server are the latest version. So I feel strange about the error.

Comment: Dear @Mark Leusink, thank you for your comment. The Domino-Administrator told me Notes client and the server are the latest version. So I feel strange about the error.